# How to adding log4j2.xml to classpath in Netbeans maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, log4j2

I am currently writing a small Maven Java application in Netbeans using sl4fj and log4j2. I am not able to use the java property `log4j.configurationFile` when deploying it in the production environment. Therefore i want log4j2 to search and find the property file within my project. I have googled around and tried, without luck, the following options;

Added the log4j2.xml to the src/main/resources folder and included it in the jar using the maven configuration (pom.xml). This actually does not include in in the classpath, but adds the xml to a location in the classpath.

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>com/reddipped/jsonlogger_2</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
</build>
```

Changed the classpath in the project properties->actions->Run project to include the xml file

```
exec.args=-classpath %classpath:/Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/log4j2.xml ${packageClassName}
```

Any other options i can try ? It is a maven project so am not able to add jars within the project properties.

-- Update 1 --

I added the property maven.test.additionalClasspath in the pom.xml including the log4j2.xml. And added a simple JUnit test.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>         
<maven.test.additionalClasspath>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/log4j2.xml</maven.test.additionalClasspath>
</properties>
```

When executing a Maven clean and build with the -X argument the log reports

```
properties used {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD ....., maven.test.additionalClasspath=/Users/petervannes/NetBeansProjects/JSONLogger_2/src/test/java/log4j2.xml, maven.compiler.target=1.6
```

Still getting the error that the log4j configuration file is not found.

```
Running com.reddipped.test.JSONLoggerTest
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) describes the method log4j is using to find the configuration.

According to that, you should just put your `log4j2.xml` file in the **default package** of your project.